# Events, Delegates in interface

Tags: c#, interface, delegates

What is better:
To use an EventHandler or having the delegate outside the interface and use it inside the interface?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Shak Smith. This type of question is impossible to answer definitely. It almost always depends on context. Do you have a specific context in mind?

Comment: It depends what you interface is describing. There are pretty significant differences between events and delegates, so application may be different depending on context. Please be more specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to create your own delegate if you need other information other than what `EventHandler` provides (essentially *what* raised the event).

If you just want to attach some data to the event you can use `EventHandler<TEventArgs>` and create your own `EventArgs` class to attach the data to.

If these events will always come from one specific type (or its sub-types) then you could create a separate `EventHandler` class that uses that type as the sender instead of `object`. One benefit of this is you don't have to check the type of the sender in the event handler.

Don't create any more types that what's necessary for a clean design.